# How substitution variables syntax '&1..' works for user/schema delimeter (“.”)

Tags: database, oracle, sqlplus

I saw this line in an oracle script

```
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO version1 FROM &1..xxdt WHERE version = 3310;
```

I don't understand the `&1..` part. I think xxdt is the name of the table, so what is the `&1..` thing in front of it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `&1` prompts for a user-entered value. Note how the entered value `mytable` is substituted for `&1` below:

```
SQL> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM &1 WHERE col1 = 12;
Enter value for 1: mytable
old   1: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM &1 WHERE col1 = 12
new   1: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mytable WHERE col1 = 12

  COUNT(*)
----------
         0
```

The dot (`.`) appends every non-space character that follows the dot to the entered value. Note how the value `table` after the dot is appended to the entered `my`:

```
SQL> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM &1.table WHERE COL1 = 12;
Enter value for 1: my
old   1: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM &1.table WHERE COL1 = 12
new   1: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mytable WHERE COL1 = 12

  COUNT(*)
----------
         0
```

The two dots in `&1..xxdt` aren't a special operator. The first dot means to append; the second dot is literal. It looks like the `&1` in your example is used to prompt for a schema/owner name. Note below how I've entered `ed` and `&1..mytable` is transformed into `ed.mytable`:

```
SQL> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM &1..mytable WHERE COL1 = 12;
Enter value for 1: ed
old   1: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM &1..mytable WHERE COL1 = 12
new   1: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ed.mytable WHERE COL1 = 12

  COUNT(*)
----------
         0
```

---

**Addendum**: Great suggestion from David Aldridge to include a quick explanation of `SET DEFINE`, which goes hand-in-hand with variable substitution. Here goes...

The substitutions above are done by SQLPlus, and its behavior can be controlled using `SET DEFINE`:

- `SET DEFINE ON` will allow the substitution and use the defined substitution character. This is normally the SQLPlus default, and was the case when I ran the queries above.
- `SET DEFINE <char>` sets the substitution character. The ampersand (`&`) is the usual default. SQLPlus will only accept non-alphanumeric, non-space characters for the substitution character. Note that I've never had to change this value in over a decade of using Oracle.
- `SET DEFINE OFF` will stop substitution. Use this if you need to have an actual literal ampersand in your query or proc, because SQLPlus will treat the ampersand as a substitution character no matter where you put it, including in a string.

Comment: +1: you might like to add a comment on the use of SET DEFINE to change the character used or disable the feature.

Comment: Thanks, and good call. I use `SET DEFINE` so infrequently it never occurred to me :) I'll add it to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the ampersand is used for substitution variables. See http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/literals-substitution-variables-and-bind-variables.php

> Substitution Variables
>
> Substitution variables are a feature of the SQL*Plus tool. They have
>   nothing to do with the way SQL is processed by the database server.
>   When a substitution variable is used in a statement, SQL*Plus requests
>   an input value and rewrites the statement to include it. The rewritten
>   statement is passed to the database. As a result, the database server
>   knows nothing of the substitution variable. The following example
>   illustrates this by repeating the previous test, this time using
>   substitution variables.

Answer (score 0):

If SET CONCAT is a period (.) and you want to append a period immediately after a substitution variable then use two periods together. For example:

```
define mycity = Melbourne
spool &mycity..log
```

is the same as:

```
spool Melbourne.log
```

https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/entry/sqlplus_101_substitution_varia#9_7

Comment: Your answer provides an example of the `&var..` usage (copy&pasted from the documentation), but you did not answer the question: what is `&1..`? And is `1` a variable?

Answer (score 0):

### Another Example:

**Create a file run.sql with below queries in vi editor:**

```
vi run.sql
    select 'mv &1..log &2._' ||to_char(sysdate,'DD-MON-YYYY-HH24-MI') || '.log' from dual;
:wq
```

**Now run:**

```
sqlplus scott/tiger @run.sql listener renamelistener
```

**Code Break Down:**

**(&1)** -first parameter "listener"

**(&2)** -second parameter "renamelistener"

**(.log)** -is a substituted of &1

**(.)** -where the single dot(.) appends non-space characters with a passing parameter value

Thanks!